# Filter a json with array of values - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter a json array that looks like the below code:

```
const data = 
  [ { __typename  : 'GEP_validate_response_graph_type'
    , status      : 'APROVADO_COM_ACOES'
    , informative : [ 'Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.'] 
    , pendencias  : 
      [ { __typename : 'GEP_validate_action_graph_type'
        , action     : 'MANIFESTACAO_OBRIGATORIA_SEM_DOCUMENTO'
        , optional   : false
        , message    : 'Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.'
        , id         : null
      } ] 
    , tarefa_id   : 'e4cdb007-a223-5547-a49f-c47c06fd2c52'
    } 
  , { __typename  : 'GEP_validate_response_graph_type'
    , status      : 'APROVADO_COM_ACOES'
    , informative : [ 'Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.'] 
    , pendencias  : 
      [ { __typename : 'GEP_validate_action_graph_type'
        , action     : 'MANIFESTACAO_OBRIGATORIA_SEM_DOCUMENTO'
        , optional   : true
        , message    : 'Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.'
        , id         : null
      } ] 
    , tarefa_id   : '361e4c79-9605-fd4f-b7bd-47a3916ad070'
  } ]
```

I want to return only the **optional == true**, and after that I will get the lenght of this object.

I tryed this, but did not work:

```
const pedido_filter = acoes_filter.pendencias.filter(
    (pendencia) =>
      pendencia.optional == true
  );
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Does `"pendencias"` always have one item\object?

Comment: I see no `acoes_filter` in your data. It's also a really bad idea to work with non-English property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for testing if the `pendencias` array contains atleast one `optional` key with value as `true`

```js
let x = [{
    "__typename": "GEP_validate_response_graph_type",
    "status": "APROVADO_COM_ACOES",
    "informative": [
      "Manifestação obrigatória sem documento."
    ],
    "pendencias": [{
      "__typename": "GEP_validate_action_graph_type",
      "action": "MANIFESTACAO_OBRIGATORIA_SEM_DOCUMENTO",
      "optional": false,
      "message": "Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.",
      "id": null
    }],
    "tarefa_id": "e4cdb007-a223-5547-a49f-c47c06fd2c52"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "GEP_validate_response_graph_type",
    "status": "APROVADO_COM_ACOES",
    "informative": [
      "Manifestação obrigatória sem documento."
    ],
    "pendencias": [{
      "__typename": "GEP_validate_action_graph_type",
      "action": "MANIFESTACAO_OBRIGATORIA_SEM_DOCUMENTO",
      "optional": true,
      "message": "Manifestação obrigatória sem documento.",
      "id": null
    }],
    "tarefa_id": "361e4c79-9605-fd4f-b7bd-47a3916ad070"
  }
];


x = x.filter((item) => item.pendencias.some(y => y.optional));
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Logic is returning both objects, one with optional as false also

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. I missed that part. @MohitKushwaha.

Comment: Just too add, there's also `Array.every()`, then again it depends on the question if pendencias really have more than 1 record and all must be optional == true.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks